# Install java 13 on ubuntu returns 404 not found error

Tags: java, ubuntu

I can't install java 13 on ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java13-installer
```

I have no previous versions installed this returns `404 Not Found` errors.

Answer (score -1):

The oracle-java13-installer package recommends installing `oracle-java13-set-default`, which makes Oracle Java 13 the default Java.

To make Oracle Java 13 default, install the oracle-java13-set-default in case it wasn't automatically installed by the Oracle Java 13 installer:

```
sudo apt install oracle-java13-set-default
```

To skip installing the oracle-java13-set-default package when installing oracle-java13-installer, use:

```
sudo apt install --no-install--recommends oracle-java13-installer
```

You can read more from this [link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/09/install-oracle-java-13-on-ubuntu-linux.html)

If nothing works, try installing the default JDK.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that this link is a good tip: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/09/install-oracle-java-13-on-ubuntu-linux.html

Follow the steps to install on Debian:

```
sudo echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-java.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 73C3DB2A
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java13-installer
```

To make Oracle Java 13 default, install the oracle-java13-set-default in case it wasn't automatically installed by the Oracle Java 13 installer:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java13-set-default
```